# How to prevent overwriting Environment Variables via .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a requirement to set a unique `Environment Variable` within server configuration. However, users should not be able to change the variable via `.htaccess` file. How can i prevent this behaviour without breaking other functions of `.htaccess`

Main requirement is to pass a unique SPECIAL_PATH variable to cgi-module

Is there any un/official module for controlling this.

Regards.